# geodjango with south causes "duplicate column name error" with spatialight db

Tags: python, django, django-south, geodjango

I have custom field for geodjango:

```python
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels

class PointField(geomodels.PointField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': CustomFormField
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(PointField, self).formfield(**defaults)


try:
    from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
    from south.introspection_plugins.geodjango import rules

    add_introspection_rules(rules, ["^project\.apps\.appname\.fields\.PointField"])
except ImportError:
    pass
```

and Django-South Migration:

```python
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding field 'Address.geoposition'
        db.add_column('company_address', 'geoposition',
                      self.gf('project.apps.appname.fields.PointField')(srid=900913, geography=True),
                      keep_default=False)


    def backwards(self, orm):
        # Deleting field 'Address.geoposition'
        db.delete_column('company_address', 'geoposition')
```

And when this migration is performed I get error:

```
AddGeometryColumn() error: "duplicate column name: geoposition"
CreateSpatialIndex() error: either "company_address"."geoposition" isn't a Geometry column or a SpatialIndex is already defined
```

I have run out of ideas and do not know how to fix this.

Software:

- Django 1.4
- spatialight 3.0.1
- gdal 1.9.2
- South 0.7.6

Geographical metadata for db was inited:

```python
subprocess.call(["spatialite", settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'], "SELECT InitSpatialMetaData();"])
```

and srs entry was added:

```python
from django.contrib.gis.utils import add_srs_entry
add_srs_entry(900913)
```

When I disable migration I got no error. Code to disable migrations:

```python
SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'appname': 'ignore',
}
```

But I need everything to work fine with migrations. Any ideas what causes the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Digging through the code, traditional alter table statements don't work with spatial fields and it tries to create a "None" column, then actually create it properly using the `AddGeometryColumn` command. However, South doesn't seem to get the hint and therefore, the `AddGeometryColumn` fails because the column is already there.

Still trying to find the answer, but I'm hoping it lies in just upgrading to newer versions. I'll keep you posted!

[Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/bc0aba7786978ec312809eae5ecb3d751608b5b7/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/spatialite/operations.py#L192)

Comment: I posted this as an issue on the Django issue tracker since it still seems to exist with new version of Django using the built in migrations system: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27072.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to override an existing model field, imo you will have to monkey patch the base class to make this work.

E.g. something like this should do the trick

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import Address

class CustomPointField(geomodels.PointField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': CustomFormField
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(PointField, self).formfield(**defaults)

Address.add_to_class('geoposition', CustomPointField())
```

I'm not sure if south will pick this up, so you might require a fresh syncdb or manual change.

Comment: No I'm not overriding field of existing model. I have my own model in my app:

class Company(models.Model): ... geoposition = CustomPointField. This is just custom field I use in my models. There are no problems with other custom fields.

Comment: And I even tried using default field:
psss = geomodels.PointField(geography=True, blank=True, default='Point(0 0)', srid=900913). Which resulted in same error